# Oracle Nested Table References

Tags: sql, oracle, object-relational-model

I have following table structure:

Table ***Customer*** with nested table ***Orders*** inside and nested table ***Positions*** as Attribute of ***Orders***.

One Attribute of ***Positions*** is ***ArtNr***.
Theres is also the Table ***Article*** with the Attribute ***ArtNr***.
And those two Attributes are in a Relation with each other.

My Problem is:

- since they are Object tables, I can't use foreign keys -> I have to use Object references (ref)
- but I don't know exactly where I have to define the ref (in ***Article*** or ***Customer*** ?)
- and I have Problems with the Oracle Syntax for ref

Comment: Why are you using nested tables in the first place? Is this homework, or are you designing your database deliberately like this? If it's the latter, I would avoid the nested tables and go for my own parent-child tables.

Comment: it's homework and we have to use object types and tables all the way

Comment: Does http://psoug.org/reference/nest_tab_cons.html help you at all?